# Is there a syntax like this in C? %[^\n]s

Tags: c, string, syntax, scanf

One of my groupmates in class told me that that syntax is used when scanning strings by using scanf but without the limit. I mean, you could scan a string using scanf and it would still scan the spaces.

```
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&string);
```

Comment: isn't it more like `scanf("%[^\n]",string);`?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",&string);` will leave `string` unchanged if the first character is a `'\n'`.  It is also susceptible to overflow attacks.  Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf( "%[^\n]", string );` will read and store everything up to (but not including) the newline character into `string`<sup>1</sup>.  Unlike the `s` conversion specifier, it will not skip over any leading whitespace (blanks, tabs, etc.).

As written, this code is susceptible to buffer overflow<sup>2</sup>; if `string` is sized to hold 10 characters and someone enters 100 characters, those extra characters will be written to the memory immediately following `string`, which can lead to all kinds of mayhem.

At the least, you would want to add a field width specifier, such as

```
scanf( "%10[^\n]", string );
```

which says "read no more than 10 characters into `string`".  Unfortunately, the field width must be specified as part of the format string; `scanf` doesn't give you a way to specify the field width as an argument, unlike `printf`.

You could build the format string dynamically, such as:

```
char fmt[20];
char string[11] = {0};

sprintf( fmt, "%%%zu[^\n]", sizeof string - 1 );
scanf( fmt, string ); // fmt contains the string "%10[^\n]"
```

This way you don't have to hardcode the field width.

Or, you could avoid that heartburn altogether and just use `fgets` instead:

```
char string[11];
...
fgets( string, sizeof string, stdin );
```

The main difference in semantics is that `fgets` *will* store the newline character into `string` if there's room, so if you don't want the newline character in your string you'll have to remove it manually:

```
char *newline = strchr( string, '\n' );
if ( newline )
  *newline = 0;   // overwrite newline character with 0 terminator
```

---

1. Meaning you'll have a stray newline hanging around in the input stream, which may or may not cause problems on the next input.

   It is more-or-less functionally equivalent to the `gets` library function, which was removed from C 2011 for this very reason (see chux's comment below for the "or less" part).

Comment: `scanf( "%[^\n]"` has functionally differences to the `gets()`.  1)  When the input is only `"\n"`, `gets(string)` forms `string` --> `""`.   `scanf( "%[^\n]",string)`does nothing to `string`.  2) `gets()` consumes the the final `'\n'`, `scanf( "%[^\n]"` does not.  `fgets()`, as you say, is the better approach.